# Extracting function variables from a list

Tags: functions, function-construction, assignment

Evaluating the following

```
func[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2

listn = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};
Map[func[##] &, listn, {1}]
```

yields

> {func[{a, b}], func[{c, d}], func[{e, f}]}

What I want to end up with is

> {func[a, b], func[c, d], func[e, f]}

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Apply` at level 1 i.e `@@@`, like this

```
func[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2
listn = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};
```

Then

```
func @@@ listn
```

This gives:

`{a^2 + b^2, c^2 + d^2, e^2 + f^2}.`

Which is equivalent to

> {func[a,b], func[c,d], func[e,f]}